# Replace elements in a string starting from known index in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had this exercise where the task was to, for lack of a better word, censor a word starting from the index 3. So let's say the generated word was Python, I had to display Pyt---. I wasn't able to solve the task but I saw other people's solutions and they went like this:

```
word = random.choice(['python', 'java', 'kotlin', 'javascript'])
x = "-" * (len(word) - 3)
n = input("Guess the word "+word[:3]+x+": > ")
```

Can someone please explain to me in English what is happening there and why is it working? I really don't understand why that works.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which specific statement in that code doesn't make sense to you?  Have you tried stepping through it line by line to see what each smaller expression returns?

Comment: The slice `word[:3]` is the first 3 letters of the word.  `"-" * (len(word) - 3)` is a string of dashes 3 shorter than the length of the word.  Concat these two together (+) to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.choice([your_list])` selects a random string from the list. Then the second `len(word)` gives you the length of characters in the string, `len(word)-3` gives you the remainder of the length after 3 has been subtracted from it, this remainder is what you what to replace with `-`, so `"-" * len(word)-3` is the numbers of hyphens required to make up the remainder of the word length after revealing the first 3 characters. Finally the last line receives input from the user,  `word[:3] prints the first three characters of the word, while` x`replaces the remaining character with hyphens. The`+`  concatenates (joins) the variables with string, so as to output it as one

Answer (score 0):

The first line chooses a random element from the list.
The second one counts the '-' characters needed from the 3rd letter of the word by getting the length of the word and subtracting 3 from it.
The 3rd one asks for user input. word[:3] means that it takes from the word string everything until index 3(everything not censored). +x adds the '-' characters(the censorship).